# Error: `fsevents` unavailable (this watcher can only be used on Darwin)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-cli

I'm cloning an existing react native app in my local environment, but every time I run `react-native run-ios` I get the following error:

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following commands produced analyzer issues:
    Analyze /Users/alydabbous/code/Dabbous-Innopay/ideal-app/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGNodeList.c normal x86_64

    Analyze /Users/alydabbous/code/Dabbous-Innopay/ideal-app/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.c normal x86_64
    Analyze Base/RCTModuleMethod.mm normal x86_64
(3 commands with analyzer issues)

The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyUros.app/MyUros normal x86_64
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TPP.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/TPP.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

And this error in react-packager:

```
Loading dependency graph...(node:52097) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: `fsevents` unavailable (this watcher can only be used on Darwin)
    at new FSEventsWatcher (/Users/alydabbous/code/Dabbous-Innopay/ideal-app/node_modules/sane/src/fsevents_watcher.js:41:11)
    at createWatcher (/Users/alydabbous/code/Dabbous-Innopay/ideal-app/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:600:23)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at HasteMap._watch (/Users/alydabbous/code/Dabbous-Innopay/ideal-app/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:747:25)
    at _buildPromise._buildFileMap.then.then.hasteMap (/Users/alydabbous/code/Dabbous-Innopay/ideal-app/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:279:21)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
(node:52097) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:52097) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I only get this error when I run `react-native run-ios` for a repo I cloned. But when I create a new react-native app everything works fine. I tried everything: killing the servers, uninstalling and installing node again, deleting my node_modules file, etc and still I can't solve this issue. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 55):

For me I uninstalled `watchman` and then reinstalled it using `brew` as shown below:

```
npm r -g watchman 
brew install watchman
```

Comment: Using MacOS Catalina and ElectronJS, and this was the only solution that worked for me

Comment: I can confirm that this works for me too in the macOS Monterey. The brew command installed a lot of things and took about 5 minutes to complete.

Answer (score 24):

```
npm install -g fsevents
```

Worked for me

Comment: `npm install fsevents` worked for me. I had to install it locally ("without `-g`") because I'm running `jest-cli` locally.

Comment: For me, updating `fsevents` to the latest fixed the issue.  I had the same error as OP with version `1.2.4`, but after upgrading to `1.2.7` the issue went away.

Comment: i was using yarn and `yarn add fsevents ` worked for me

Answer (score 8):

I faced the following issue while coding a react native app.
It seemed to be an error with watchman, so all we need is to re-install it:

`brew remove watchman`

`brew install watchman`

I hope it helps,

Comment: `brew install watchman` gave me an error until i did `brew update`. That in itself took about 30 minutes. But then it all worked perfectly thank u!

Comment: This is what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error when trying to run jest watch. 
Simple solution for me was to install the fsevents module through npm (which I assume this is what your error message is telling you).
I was also working with a React app and had additional similar errors.

Hope this helps!

Comment: don't know why in the world this worked but yes, I was getting fsevents problems with multiple versions of yarn add. When I switched to npm it worked. WTH but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

This happened in a `create-react-app` for me. I resolved this by updating `react-scripts`

`yarn add react-scripts@latest`

Then deleting `node_modules`, and re-installing

`yarn`

Comment: This worked for me, didn't have to delete nm and reinstall though. `npm i react-scripts@latest`

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling watchman and then reinstalling with brew worked:

```
npm r -g watchman
```

then

```
brew install watchman
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this issue could be related to the node version you are running. If you are using nvm, try switching to a different node version and see if it fixes. It worked for me on a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, following a MacOS update, I needed the updated version of `yarn`.

```
curl --compressed -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
```